# How could I fill all the space in the dockpanel?

Tags: wpf

I have this 2 grids:

```
<Grid Margin="2.0cm, 2.0cm, 1.5cm, 0.5cm" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >


    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Background="Red">
        <Grid Height="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Blue"/>
        <Grid Height="100" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Yellow"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

The result is this:

[image]

I would like the blue grid fill all the space until the yellow grid and the yellow grid should to fill all the space until the bottom. So I didn't want to see red color.

Also, I would like that if the yellow grid is collapsed, the blue grid should to fill all the space.

I have to set vertical alignement to stretch, but I don't get the desire behaviour, in this case I wouldn't see the grids.

How could I get the behaviour that I want?

Thanks so much.

**SOLUTION**

I can solve the problem with this code:

```
<Grid Margin="2.0cm, 2.0cm, 1.5cm, 0.5cm" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Yellow" Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Blue" Visibility="Visible" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: "the blue grid should to fill all the space" - not going to happen with `Height="100"`

Comment: Yes, I know, it was just an example to show that I have 2 grids. If I set vertical alignement to strecth they are not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use UniformGrid if you want your grids to equally share the space. If the yellow grid is collapsed the blue grid will fill the entire space.

```
<Grid Margin="2.0cm, 2.0cm, 1.5cm, 0.5cm" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <UniformGrid Background="Red" Columns="1">
        <Grid Background="Blue"/>
        <Grid Background="Yellow"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is close to the expected behaviour, but I would like to se the second grid with height of 100, alginement to bottom and the blue grid should to fill all the space until the yellow grid.

Comment: If the yellow grid will always be 100px then you can use a DockPanel. But you should change the order of the grids in the DockPanel to allow blue grid to use remaining space, because last child fills the remaining space. Also blue grid should not have Height property.